# Copying data to new workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need this to copy all of the data from one spreadsheet, create a new workbook, name it, and paste the data. I seem to have a bug in my code that opens two new workbooks, pastes my data in one and pastes the last thing I copied into the other and that is the file that it assigns the name to.

```
' Copy the sheet(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy


' Create new Workbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

' Name it and paste data
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="test.xlsx"
NewBook.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your active sheet is not necessarily `NewBook`. You have to activate the workbook first as per:

```
' Copy the sheet(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy


' Create new Workbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

' Name it and paste data
NewBook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:="test.xlsx"
NewBook.Close
```